# nginx -c, set configuration file

Tags: nginx

Trying to set config file. Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. User root.

```
nginx -s quit

nginx -c /home/webapps/confs/nginx.conf

nginx -V
```

> ...--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf...

```
nginx -s quit

nginx -c /home/webapps/confs/nginx.conf -t
```

> nginx: the configuration file /home/webapps/confs/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>
> nginx: configuration file /home/webapps/confs/nginx.conf test is
>   successful

```
nginx -V
```

> ...--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't override the default location for the config path as far as I know, but need to pass it in if that's your intent. The invocations of "-V" are independent instances

Comment: thanks. It's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-p` option to specify the prefix path:

```
nginx -p /home/webapps/confs/ -c nginx.conf
```